# How can I make G=HK?

Tags: group-theory

Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $G:$group. Suppose the mapping $f:H\times K\to G$ defined by $(h,k)\to hk$ is injective, surjective, and operation-preserving. Show that $G=HK.$

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that $HK\subset G$. Now, for all $g\in G$, since $f$ is surjective, there are $h\in H,k\in K$ such that $g=hk\in HK$. Therefore $G=HK$.